# Hola , soy nuevo en esto y queria consultar que esta mal en mi codigo

Tags: c, bucles

La consigna consistia en poder ingresar 10 transacciones y elegir en que local fueron echas y en cuanto dinero consistia esa transaccion, no entiendo porque el ciclo me funciona mal y lo mire mil veces, probablemente sea un error de principiante pero si me podrian ayudar seria genial .

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define TAM 10
int main(){
    
    double t[TAM];
    double p[TAM];
    char c;
    double din;
    
    printf("ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P");
    
    
    for(int d=0;d<TAM;d++){
        printf("ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P \n");
        scanf("%c",&c);
        fflush(stdin);
        c = toupper(c);
    
      if(c=='T'){
        printf("Digite la cantidad que facturo Tigre \n");
        scanf("%lf",&din);
        t[d] += din;
    } else if(c =='P'){
        printf("Digite la cantidad que facturo Pilar \n");
        scanf("%lf",&din);
        p[d] += din;
    } 
    
        
    }
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! decis que anda mal.. que es lo que hace, y que deberia hacer?

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Answer (score 2):

Ya que no especificas cual es el error, supongo que te refieres a esto:

```
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
T
Digite la cantidad que facturo Tigre
10
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
```

A que se salta la siguiente lectura.

Y la solución es relativamente simple:

Cuando lees la cantidad, en cualquiera de los 2 casos, el stream queda sucio.

```
    printf("Digite la cantidad que facturo Tigre \n");
    scanf("%lf",&din); // El usuario ingresa "10\n"
    t[d] += din;       // Y pasado en el stream queda "\n"
```

Luego cuando vas a leer el carácter lee el `\n` que quedo en el stream.

```
    scanf("%c", &c);
```

Supongo que tu ya sabias de el problema, ya que tienes esto:

```
    fflush(stdin);
```

Pero déjame informarte que eso no es correcto. Según el estándar de C, es
comportamiento indefinido hacer `fflush(stdin)`. Lo que puedes hacer es cuando
lees el numero, ignorar un carácter después de la lectura. Para ignorar algo
leído con `scanf` puedes colocar un `*` después del `%`. Te quedaría de la
siguiente manera.

```
    scanf("%lf%*c", &din);
```

De esa manera tu código funciona correctamente.

## Nota

> no entiendo porque el ciclo me funciona mal

Y para nosotros recién leyendo tu código tampoco se nos hace obvio. Es buena
idea que nos digas que es lo que esperabas que pasara, y lo que pasa en
realidad.

No es complicado que agregues en la pregunta:

Yo esperaba que hiciera esto:

```
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
T
Digite la cantidad que facturo Tigre
10
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
P
Digite la cantidad que facturo Pilar
10
```

Pero se salta la segunda lectura de la ubicación:

```
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
T
Digite la cantidad que facturo Tigre
10
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
ingrese la inicial de la ubicacion del local, T o P
```

Igual en tu titulo, en lugar de:

> Hola , soy nuevo en esto y quería consultar que esta mal en mi código

Puedes colocar algo como:

> `scanf` se salta la lectura de un carácter.

Con el primer titulo no se de que va la pregunta, con el segundo titulo
prácticamente ya se cual va a ser la solución.

Mucha suerte!

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la ayuda, tenes razon mi pregunta estuvo muy mal formulada , perdone estoy aprendiendo